# If user input is negative, prompt again

Tags: c, if-statement, while-loop, cs50

So I'm calculating money change, if the user's input is `0.41` the result will be: `1 quarter, 1 dime, 1 nickel, 1 penny`.

The code works fine, until you provide a negative value.
I added an if statement to check for that, and all I could do is `exit(0)` afterwards. I want to re-prompt the user to enter a positive value, again and again, how can I do that?

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    printf("How much change do you owe: ");

    float amount = GetFloat();
    float cents = 100.0 * amount;
    float quarter = 0;
    float dime = 0;
    float nickel = 0;
    float penny = 0;

    if (amount < 0) {
        printf("Please provide a positive value.");
        exit(0);
    }

    while (cents > 0) {
        if (cents >= 25.0) {
            cents -= 25.0;
            quarter += 1;
        } else if (cents >= 10.0) {
            cents -= 10.0;
            dime += 1;
        } else if (cents >= 5.0) {
            cents -= 5.0;
            nickel += 1;
        } else if (cents >= 1.0) {
            cents -= 1.0;
            penny += 1;
        }
    }
    printf("%f quarters, %f dimes, %f nickels, %f pennies, Total of %f coins.\n", quarter, dime, nickel, penny, quarter + dime + nickel + penny);
}
```

Comment: That `while` loop you have further down in *your* code. Try one of those wrapped around your input sequence.

Comment: Use a do-while loop? BTW please don't use `float` for money and change problems, you will get strange errors due inexact representation. Better to work in cents using `int`.

Comment: Computing money using `float` is a [bad idea](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/08/14/currency-rounding-errors/).  Use an integer type instead.  When it comes time to display dollars, scale it at display time.

Comment: This is part of a course I'm taking, they explicitly asked us to use `float` alongside `GetFloat()` which is coming from `#include <cs50.h>`

Comment: Of course, it's in the name, but the point is that (when not at the mercy of courses and their prescriptions) there are strong reasons to avoid floating-point types when needing exact comparisons.

Comment: Sounds like a bad course using floating point for currency. For instance, you canot even represent `0.1` _exactly_ in a binary float.

Comment: They do mention that in the problem set description: `Incidentally, do beware the inherent imprecision of floating-point values. For instance, 0.01 cannot be represented exactly as a float.`

Comment: For those remarking about the code quality of learners, which will already not compare to that of more experienced novices, CS50 itself is _not_ necessarily meant to teach C or any programming language properly. In particular, [read this notice for the CS50 Appliance](https://manual.cs50.net/appliance/2014/#notice_2). Moreover, [the CS50 library](https://manual.cs50.net/library/) attempts to simplify more than just user input in C. It also attempts to simplify authentication in languages like PHP, Python, and Ruby.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be a bit awkward to get your head around where to put declarations as a newbie, so here it is:

```
float amount;

for (;;)
{
    amount = GetFloat();

    if ( amount >= 0 ) 
        break;

    printf("Please provide a positive value.\n");
}

float cents = 100.0 * amount;
float quarter = 0;
// etc.
```

You can't put `float amount` inside the `{ }` otherwise that variable would be scoped to that scope, and not accessible after the `}`.

A more compact way of writing the same loop would be:

```
while( (amount = GetFloat()) < 0 )
    printf("Please provide a positive value.");
```

but you can use whichever version looks more sensible to you.

Comment: NB. as mentioned by others, floating point is a bad way to represent money because of rounding errors.

Comment: Nice use of `break` and the final highly compact version. However, I'm not sure why you talk about avoiding confusing new coders, then immediately use `for (;;)`! Of course, they're equivalent, but the usual `while (1)` seems more understandable. A lot of new coders I've seen struggle to grasp exactly what the three 'sub-clauses' in the `for` brackets really do.

Comment: @underscore_d now's as good a time as any to learn that `for(;;)` means a loop that will keep going until it's exited by `break;` (or another control statement). It is a common pattern

Comment: Thank you, that worked. However, I don't understand the meaning of `for (;;)` what does it mean?

Comment: And yet without me bringing it up, the OP would not have had that explanation or the confirmation that it's semantically equivalent.

Comment: @underscore_d congratulations

Comment: @Halnex sometimes called an "infinite loop", it means that the loop will keep looping until you exit the loop in some other way  (in my case the `break` statement).   If you leave out the exit condition (the thing between the two semicolons in a `for`), that's what happens.

Answer (score 2):

```
float amount;
do
{
    amount = GetFloat();
}
while (0 < amount);
```

Edit: Matt wins for including the message telling the user *why* they're being looped, of course.